# Matching range values to worksheet names then finding a cell and copying the value beside it

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets

1. Source(ThisWorkbook) - contains multiple worksheets
2. Destination(WBD) - contains 1 worksheet

This is the process:

1. Compare each cell from a range in WBD (B2:B6) to all worksheet names in ThisWorkbook
2. If a match is found, from a range in WBD (C2:C7) and look for it in the matched worksheet
3. (this is where I'm having troubles)How do I get the value of the avg price cell? Do I need another loop?

*the distance between type and price is consistent.

Here's what I got so far:

```
For Each cel In WBD.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B6")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
            If ws.Name = cel.Value Then
                'find C2:C7 , offset, copy avg price, paste
    Next ws
Next cel
```

Source - ThisWorkbook

[image: Source - ThisWorkbook]

Destination - WBD

[image: Destination - WBD]

Answer (score 1):

### A Lookup by Worksheets

**An `Application.Match` Approach**

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookupValues()

    Const dFirst As Long = 2
    Const sFirst As Long = 2
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    'Dim WBD As Workbook: Set WBD = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dLast As Long
    With WBD.Worksheets(1)
        dLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' because merged in 'B'
        Set drg = .Cells(dFirst, "B").Resize(dLast - dFirst + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dMatch As Variant
    Dim sMatch As Variant
    Dim sLast As Long
    
    For Each src In swb.Worksheets
        sLast = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srg = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set srg = src.Cells(sFirst, "B").Resize(sLast - sFirst + 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            dMatch = Application.Match(src.Name, drg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(dMatch) Then
                Set cel = drg.Cells(dMatch)
                Do
                    sMatch = Application.Match(cel.Offset(, 1).Value, srg, 0)
                    If IsNumeric(sMatch) Then
                        cel.Offset(, 2).Value _
                            = srg.Cells(sMatch).Offset(3, 2).Value
                    End If
                    Set cel = cel.Offset(, 1).Offset(1, -1) ' because merged
                Loop Until Len(cel.Value) > 0 Or cel.Row > dLast
            End If
        End If
    Next src
    
    'WBD.Save
    'swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what each line does. Can you enlighten me on `With WBD.Worksheets(1)
        dLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' because merged in 'B'
        Set drg = .Cells(dFirst, "B").Resize(dLast - dFirst + 1)
    End With`

Comment: It first calculates the last row in column `C` because in column `B` the result could be wrong because of merged cells. Then it defines the `Destination (Read) Column Range` in column `B` using as the first row the constant `dFirst` and for the last row the just calculated `dLast` (in your image `B2:B7`; the calculated last row in column `B` would result in `B2:B6`(wrong)).

Comment: The `Resize` part is a little bit tricky. You have `.Cells(dFirst, "B")` which is the same as `.Range("B" & dFirst)` or in this particular case `B2`. Imagine the calculated last row was row `7`. If you do `Range("B2").Resize(7 - 2 + 1)` you can simplify `Range("B2").Resize(6)` which in the end is `Range("B2:B7")` (Not `Range("B2:B8")`). Note that `Range("A1").Resize(1)` is still `Range("A1")` and `Range("A1").Resize(2)` is `Range("A1:A2")`, while `Range("A1").Offset(1)` is `Range("A2")`.

Comment: Could you help me modify the code if the row/cols are setup like this? https://imgur.com/a/khG6oNA

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub m1()
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B6")
        If cel.MergeCells Then  
            shname = cel.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value    ' if cells merged, only first cell contains value
        Else
            shname = cel.Value
        End If
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = shname Then
                Set f = ws.Columns("B").Find(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then ' its found
                    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("avg price", after:=f.Offset(0, 1))
                    If Not f Is Nothing Then ' its found
                        cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the avg price is in Single data type. I am trying to find out why the code is not working on my end.

Comment: The data type does not matter in this case, since the instruction cel.Offset (0, 2) .Value = f.Offset (0, 1) .Value assigns the cell on the left a value of any type from the cell on the right. As for the reasons for the inoperability of this code, this is usually solved by debugging the code step by step

Comment: Do I need to declare f?

Comment: Variables in VBA do not have to be declared, without declaration they are of type Variant. The need to declare variables depends on whether there is an Option Explicit statement in the module.

Comment: I think I got my error, the value I am finding in B is a merged cell. Also the avg price cell and the cell on the right of it are also merged cell. How do I solve this?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment - if cells merged, only first cell contains value. You can operate on the cel.MergeArea range, for example, as shown in the listing. Another option is to initially refuse to merge cells.